# Angular Ng Xorro table col background change

Tags: css, angular, typescript, ng-zorro-antd

I'm using my angular project for the antd **[NG-ZORRO Table](https://ng.ant.design/version/9.3.x/components/table/en)**, so dose any know know how to add table special col for the background color?

Image explain here

[image]
here is my code

**html**

```
<nz-table #basicTable [nzData]="dataSet">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of basicTable.data">
      <td>{{data.name}}</td>
      <td>{{data.age}}</td>
      <td>{{data.address}}</td>
      <td>
        <a>Action 一 {{data.name}}</a>
        <nz-divider nzType="vertical"></nz-divider>
        <a>Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</nz-table>
```

.ts

```
export class NzDemoTableBasicComponent {
  listOfData: Person[] = [
    {
      key: '1',
      name: 'John Brown',
      age: 32,
      address: 'New York No. 1 Lake Park'
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      name: 'Jim Green',
      age: 42,
      address: 'London No. 1 Lake Park'
    },
    {
      key: '3',
      name: 'Joe Black',
      age: 32,
      address: 'Sidney No. 1 Lake Park'
    }
  ];
}
```

Comment: can you please elaborate more to explain your question, exactly what you want to do and what you suffer for an issue ?

Comment: @RBC Hello, I want to know how to do table col to add ed some background like my attached image, lease refer my updated question

Comment: sorry for late response but i have one way, you can add color property to every object of your listOfData array and then can be applied to html element be like [style.backgroundColor]="'{{data.color}}'".

Comment: @RBC Thank you for your valuable time and guidance. I will apply what you suggested

Comment: Okay please let me know if it works for you or not else will find out another way.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to do it dynamically the object must change to this

```
interface Person {
  key: string;
  name: { value: string; colored: boolean };
  age: { value: number; colored: boolean };
  address: { value: string; colored: boolean };
}
```

I add value for the value of the property and colored if we want colored col
so the array of data will be like this

```
 listOfData: Person[] = [
    {
      key: '1',
      name: { value: 'John Brown1', colored: true },
      age: { value: 32, colored: false },
      address: { value: 'New York No. 1 ', colored: false },
    },
    {
      key: '2',
      name: { value: 'John Brown2', colored: false },
      age: { value: 55, colored: false },
      address: { value: 'New York No. 2', colored: true },
    },
    {
      key: '3',
      name: { value: 'John Brown3', colored: false },
      age: { value: 18, colored: false },
      address: { value: 'New York No. 3', colored: false },
    },
  ];
```

and HTML It will be like this

```
<nz-table #basicTable [nzData]="listOfData">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>Name</th>
      <th>Age</th>
      <th>Address</th>
      <th>Action</th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr *ngFor="let data of basicTable.data">
      <td  [style.background]="data.name.colored ? 'yellow' : ''">{{ data.name.value 
      }}</td>
      <td [style.background]="data.age.colored ? 'yellow' : ''">{{ data.age.value }} 
      </td>
      <td [style.background]="data.address.colored ? 'yellow' : ''">{{ 
       data.address.value }}</td>
      <td>
        <a>Action 一 {{ data.name.value }}</a>
        <nz-divider nzType="vertical"></nz-divider>
        <a>Delete</a>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</nz-table>
```

final result It will be like this

[image]

you can see the code in stackblitz from [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-nwjt2c)